# How to query a DynamoDB Table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I need to query a DynamoDB Table in Javascript to get a single item from the table.
This is my query:

```
         const query = {
            TableName: 'Follower-nxh5zsywmfb3xktilogkn6mvr4-dev',
            IndexName: 'followerByFollowerID',
            KeyConditionExpression: '#followerID = :followerValue AND #followingID = :followingValue',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':followerValue': {S: profileID.toString()},
                ':followingValue':{S: item.followerID.toString()},

            },
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                '#followerID': 'followerID',
                '#followingID': 'followingID',
            },
            Limit: 1
        };
```

But I am getting this error: `Query key condition not supported`.
How to perform a query with two conditions `followingID` and `followerID`?

Comment: What is the Key Structure in that Index? I.e. which is the partition and which the sort key?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the `followerByFollowerID` index as well as of other indexes on your table?

Comment: Check out this photo [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12VR-CJYd_ujlGYGkTz1wIA-wbvtrQCIO/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

For the `Query` you are making you need to ensure that your table/index conforms to with the keys you use in your `KeyConditionExpression`. In this case your index followerByFollowerID should have the following schema:

| key type | key name | data type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| partition | followerID | string |
| sort | followingID | string |

If your index does not have this schema, your Query will fail with: `Query key condition not supported` which is what you are witnessing.

Comment: This  is the structure of the keys https://drive.google.com/file/d/12VR-CJYd_ujlGYGkTz1wIA-wbvtrQCIO/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you define a sort key?